# Error appear related to JS for Toggle Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already declare ID in my `<div>`, however an error appear, how to solve this error.

[image]

Below is my Code for reference

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-column="0" class="toggle-vis" data-label-text="No" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" data-column="1" class="toggle-vis" data-label-text="Region" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" data-column="2" class="toggle-vis" data-label-text="IBSE Node" checked/>
 </div>
<div>
 <table class="data-table stripe hover multiple-select-row nowrap" id="example">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">No</th>
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>IBSE Node</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onColor = 'success';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offColor = 'danger';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'mini';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.state = 'false';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.inverse = 'true';
        $(".toggle-vis").bootstrapSwitch();
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $('.toggle-vis').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have created an example from the source code you have provided which seems to be working just fine. Can you explain what is missing from the demo I have create to get the same error you have. Thank you [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/wmghsc23/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant reinitialize datatable you need to destroy it before initialize again.
add this lines inside your toggle function.

```
$("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Comment: Thank You, I jut put this line code between toggle and it solved my problem.